# Undefined reference to foo::bar static ofstream

Tags: c++

I've been trying to compile a program I've spent the past three days building, and I can't figure out how to get it to stop throwing an error.  I keep getting the compile error "undefined reference to Foo::bar" where "bar" is a static ofstream declared in the Foo.h file.

**Foo.h**

```
Class Foo
{
    public:
          <insert methods>
    private:
          static ofstream& bar;
 }
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "EventReport.h"
using namespace std;

Foo::Foo()
{
   bar.open("foobar.txt");
}
```

I keep getting the error message on the "bar" in Foo.cpp (there are multiple in the file).  Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 0):

```
undefined reference to Foo::bar
```

That error means that you told the compiler this object exists...

```
class Foo {
      static ofstream& bar;
};
```

...and the compiler decided to use it.

But you never defined it.  It's undefined.

Add this to Foo.cpp:

```
ofstream& Foo::bar = (something);
```

Comment: ... I should write a macro.  :)

Comment: What type should 'something' be?  I'm still trying to learn C++ concepts.

Comment: @johwiltb, It should refer to an existing `ofstream` object.